# Return true if string contains "|"

Tags: r, grepl

to check if a string contains a given element we can do

```
strings <- c("4|x|4", "4x4", "1|x|1")
element <- "4"
grepl(element, strings)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

but if the element is a `|` this no longer works.

```
 grepl("|", strings)
 #[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

How can we return `TRUE`,`FALSE`,`TRUE`?

Comment: Use `grep("|", strings, fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

The `|` is a metacharacter meaning `OR` or either.  To evaluate the literal string value, either escape (`\\`) or place it inside brackets (`[]`) or use the `fixed = TRUE` argument

```
grepl("|", strings, fixed = TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```